# How to update existed payload value in Mule DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am new to DataWeave and I want to update below payload **placeId** value with **topValue** when placeId not EMPTY , I tried below code but not working , Can some one help me please?

Code

--

```
%dw 2.0

output application/json

import update from dw::util::Values

var referralPayload = {"data":1,"placeId":"BSSE","topValue":1000}

---

    referralPayload update(referralPayload.placeId) with if(referralPayload.placeId != null and referralPayload.placeId != "")referralPayload.topValue else referralPayload.placeId
```

Expected Result:

---

```
{

"data": 1,

"placeId": "1000",

"topValue": 1000

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the field name as String in the update function.
If you change your expression to `referralPayload update('placeId') with`  then your dw will work.

To use the complicated conditional logic while updating I would recommend using the [`update`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dw-operators#update-operator) operator rather than using `dw::util::Values::update` function because it provides a more clear and readable syntax

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var referralPayload = {"data":1,"placeId":"BSSE","topValue":1000}
---
referralPayload  update {
        case .placeId ->  if(!isEmpty($)) referralPayload.topValue else $
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two approaches based on your requirement:

1. Using the "update" operator:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var referralPayload = {"data":1,"placeId":"BSSE","topValue":1000}
---
referralPayload update {
        case .placeId ->  if(!isEmpty($)) referralPayload.topValue else $
}
```

2. Using the "update" function:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import update from dw::util::Values
var referralPayload = {"data":1,"placeId":"BSSE","topValue":1000}
---
referralPayload update "placeId" with (if(!isEmpty(referralPayload.placeId)) referralPayload.topValue else referralPayload.placeId)
```

Approach 1 is more optimized:

1. importing a library is always a costlier process
2. use of "update" operator can be used as a switch case that is more efficient in case of multiple updates operations